# Official nginx docker gives 403 Forbidden when serving static files

Tags: docker, nginx, static-html

I'm using [nginx docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) to serve a simple index.html file.
As mentioned in the quick guid, I have a Dockerfile containing:

```
FROM nginx

COPY www-root-dir /usr/share/nginx/html
```

(`www-root-dir` just contains an `index.html` file)
But when I run this image, it returns 403 Forbidden. And in logs it says:

```
 [error] 7#7: *2 "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied),
```

I've searched about this and know it's about file permissions.
But what permission/owner should I set for that? I've tried `chown`ing to `www-data` and `nginx`. Also `chmod`ing `+rwx` didn't help.
My question is: What exactly should I do? And whatever the solution is, why it's not mentioned in the official docs?

#### Edit:

I also tried without the custom html file.
This simple Dockerfile yet responds the same:

```
FROM nginx
# Just it!
```

Comment: Could you run successfully without custom html file? Have you mapped 80 port ?

Comment: @Andrea Port is OK as I connect and see the nginx 403 message!
But, without the index.html the same error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY directory_containing_index  /usr/share/nginx/html
```

This is working fine for me.

alpine versions are very small in sizes compare to their counterparts like ubuntu.
you can test it without defining your own Dockerfile like,

`docker run --rm -v /directory_containing_index:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 8080:80 nginx:alpine`

Comment: It means the nginx:latest is buggy and wont work?
However, I accepted the answer, as bypassed my problem. Thanks